# How to auto generate a ID with random numbers in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example I had a column named 'ID'
I want to get the output as

```
ID
---
ABCXX708
ABCXX976
ABCXX654
ABCXX081
```

In short ABCXX should be common for every row but the remaining 3 numbers should be random and integer..

Comment: Question is not clear. Add some sample data

Comment: Is it always three number at the end or it can be any number of digits

Comment: always a three number digit

Comment: You do understand that this only has 1000 unique combinations, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with t (n) as (select 0 union all select n+1 from t where n <100)

select    'ABC' 
        + format(n,'00') 
        + cast(cast(rand(cast(newid() as varbinary(100)))*10 as int) as char(1))

from    t
```

Alternative solution

```
with t (n) as (select 0 union all select n+1 from t where n <100)

select    'ABC' 
        + right ('0' + cast(n as varchar(2)),2)
        + cast(cast(rand(cast(newid() as varbinary(100)))*10 as int) as char(1))

from    t
```

Comment: it gives an error "'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.
"

Comment: iam using sql server 2008 version it seems there is no format built fin function

Comment: Check the alternative solution

Comment: Working ...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this

```
select 'ABCXX'+CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-100)+100) as varchar(3)) 'id'
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer for my question check it out    :-                  with t (n) as (select 0 union all select n+1 from t where n <100)

select    'ABC' 
        + right ('0' + cast(n as varchar(2)),2)
        + cast(cast(rand(cast(newid() as varbinary(100)))*10 as int) as char(1))

from    t

Answer (score 0):

With the `RAND()` function you can get Random numbers. And For the 'ABCXX' you can follow your previous logic.

```
SELECT CAST(RAND()*10.00 AS INT)
```

The above RAND() function will give values between 0.0 to 1.0 in decimals every time you hit the Statement. To make it for a single digit Multiply with 10 and Cast it to INT to remove the next decimal values.

Reference "  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx)

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL Server RAND()?

Comment: Yes you are. Run this: `with t (n) as (select 1 union all select n+1 from t where n <100) SELECT rand() from t`

Comment: @ShakeerMirza - `RAND()` will not be evaluated for each row thats what he is trying to point out

Comment: Thank you @Prdp I thought that it is for getting ID per row Insert.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2012 you have `FORMAT` function and `SEQUENCE` object. Hence the below query will work.

First you need to create a Sequence object.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE DemopSeq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Then the following query will generate results as per your requirement.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ABC',FORMAT(NEXT VALUE FOR DemopSeq, '00'),ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 10))
```

Hope this helps.